# Excel: Returning value after checking column, using this column to define range for MIN, using MIN(value) to retrieve column 'name'

Tags: excel, excel-2010

For a business 'tool' in excel I need to do retrieve a location corresponding to a postcode. The location is found by first looking up the postcode in a column, checking the min value in the corresponding row and returning the location based on which column this MIN value is in.

For looking up the column that corresponds with my postcode, I use the function 
"=MATCH("cell";"range")" which gives me the row number on which this postcode is found in my range. next I use this row number to define my range for the MIN function so I can retrieve the lowest corresponding number in the row corresponding to my found postcode in the range. This already works. What I can't seem to figure out is how do I use the location of the MIN value to retrieve the location corresponding to this value's column, or: The MIN value is searched in lets say range "D3:G3". If the min Value is in cell D3, I need to retrieve the 'location' corresponding to the D column (which is in lets say D100). So if the min value for range "D3:G3" is in cell D3 I need to display the value of D100 as the result.

My problem is that I when I get the MIN value from a range (always in a row), I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the address of the cell of this value and use this to get the value of the 'name' of the column which is my location that I want to retrieve when entering the postcode.

I hope this is explained clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think you will need to use another MATCH function to find the column of the MIN value. Once you know the column and the row, you can use the OFFSET function to retrieve the value of the cell. So below I am assuming you will put the first MATCH from your question, which returns the row number, in cell H1:

In H2: =MATCH(D3:G3, MIN(D3:G3), 0) 'would return the position of the minimum value in the range

In H3: =OFFSET(D3, H1-3, H2-1) 'this should give you the result you want. You might need to adjust the formula slightly, changing the -3 and -1 values.

Answer (score 0):

A common method to do this is with `INDEX` and `MATCH` - like this

`=INDEX(D100:G100,MATCH(MIN(D3:G3),D3:G3,0))`

That formula uses `MATCH` to find the position of the minimum value in `D3:G3`, then `INDEX` retrieves the value from the same column but in row `100`

`INDEX` is normally preferable to `OFFSET` because it's not a **volatile** function